# What does it mean that a distribution is a generalized function and why are generalized eigenvectors distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, distribution-theory, generalized-eigenvector

I am studying eigenvalues and eigenvectors of operators on infinite-dimensional spaces, and I am struggling to understand generalized eigenvectors.

In order to explain myself better, I'm going to refer to an exercise we did during class.
We had to find a basis for $L^2(R)$ using eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors of the operator $P=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ defined on $D=\{f, f' \in L^2(R), f \space absolutely\space continuous\}$.
In this way, P is self-adjoint.
So we use the eigenvalues equation:
$$-i\frac{df}{dx}=\lambda f$$
And we find the eigenvectors:
$$f_n=a_\lambda e^{i\lambda x}$$
where $\lambda$ is a real number and $a_\lambda$ is a coefficient.
These functions though $\notin L^2(R)$, so they're generalized eigenvectors and they're part of the continuous spectrum.

And this is the part I didn't understand.
First of all, during lesson, my professor said that generalized eigenvectors are not functions but distributions.

My first doubt is the following: she said that $L^2(R) \subset S'(R)$ (where $S'(R)$ is the space of tempered distributions) and that $L^2(R)$ is dense in $S'(R)$.
So, I know distributions are also known as generalized functions, but I really don't understand why, and I don't understand in which way we can say that $L^2(R)$ that is a space of functions can be included in a space of distributions. So, in particular, knowing that the generalized eigenvector we found should be a distribution, I don't understand how $f_n=a_\lambda e^{i\lambda x}$ can be seen as a distribution.

I get the idea that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f_n(x)|^2dx$$ is infinite, while $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f_n(x)\phi(x)|^2dx$$ where $\phi$ is a test function, is finite.
But we defined a distribution as follows:
$$T_f(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx$$
So if T is defined as that integral, how can it be seen as a function?

In addition, we also said that, for a self-adjoint operator, the set of the eigenvectors united to the set of the generalized eigenvectors forms an orthogonal basis of $L^2(R)$: but how is it possible that the generalized eigenvectors, which are not in $L^2(R)$, are a part of its basis?

Comment: Not a complete answer but a nice reference for the first question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1946353/998803

Comment: Well, $\Psi_{\lambda}(x)=e^{i\lambda x}$ cannot be a basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ since they are not square integrable functions. Making an appropriate basis out of these generalized eigenvectors may require a "smoothing procedure" that makes them $L^2$ integrable [see the answer by DisintegratingByParts here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927614/basis-of-l2-mathbb-r-and-fourier-transform)

Comment: How to see functions as distributions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527480/proof-that-the-dirac-delta-function-is-the-sum-of-exponentials-distributions-up/